# Удовлетворяет ли строка условию?

Tags: c#

Есть массив фильтров, к примеру

```
string[] str ={"*.pdf","?file_*.DOC"}
```

Есть строка Path, которая содержит путь к файлу. Вопрос в том, как узнать удовлетворяет ли хоть одному фильтру данная строка Path или нет? Есть метод один System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(), в него можно передать фильтр в виде строки и он возвращает массив путей, которые соответствуют фильтру. Может есть подобный инструмент, который позволил бы решить мою задачу?

Comment: Ну, хм. Вот исходник функции: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/io/system/io/PatternMatcher.cs. Но он отмечен как internal.

Comment: Можно написать метод-расширение, туда положить логику, что передавая путь и массив фильтров, возвращается true|false.

Comment: всю логику, выходит, руками писать?

Comment: VladD, функция - огонь. Передаю шаблон, передаю строку - все работает. Спасибо. Плюс еще и вся логика расписана

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: Ну, хорошо, если помогло. Пожалуйста!

Comment: Еще вариант: метод [`LikeOperator.LikeString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.likeoperator.likestring.aspx). И классический подход, основанный на `Regex`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146349/2878550